# input in array with help of setter in java (Edited)

Tags: java, input, setter

i want to input some name in array with help of setter ... this is my code ...
may you help me how to do it ?? thanks in advane.

//this is class myclass with input statement 
//my problem is the program say Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        //at studentproject.MyClass.AddList(MyClass.java:27)
        //at studentproject.Main.main(Main.java:20)
//        Java Result: 1
//where of my program has problem ???

```
public class MyClass
{
     Student St = new Student();

     Student[]Array1 = new Student[10];
     Student[]ArrayF1 = new Student[10];

     void AddList()
     {

            Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            for (int i=0; i<Array1.length & i<ArrayF1.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Student NAME Number " + (i+1) + ":");
                Array1[i].setName(Scan.next());


                //System.out.println("Enter Student MARK Number " + (i+1) + ":");
                //St.setMark(Scan.nextFloat());
            }

    }

}
```

// this is my Student class with all setter and getter

```
public class Student
{
private String Name;
private float Mark;

/**
 * @return the Name
 */
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

/**
 * @param Name the Name to set
 */
public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

/**
 * @return the Mark
 */
public float getMark() {
    return Mark;
}

/**
 * @param Mark the Mark to set
 */
public void setMark(float Mark) {
    this.Mark = Mark;
}
```

another problem is when i want to print the array the memory address of array printed, not the value of array ... where is my problem ...what is printed is like this ...Enter Student NAME Number 10:
dddddd
"studentproject.Student@1b67f74"

```
    void PrintList()
    {

            for (int i=0; i<Array1.length; i++)
            {

                System.out.println(Array1[i]);

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Student[]Array1 = new Student[10];
```

Doesn't actually give you 10 properly constructed `Student` objects.  What it does is allocates enough space to hold 10 properly constructed `Student` objects.  So what happens is in each iteration over the array it calls `null.setName`.  This results in an NPE.

If you want to construct the `Student` onjects after allocation you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0;i<Array1.length;i++)
{  
    Array1[i] = new Student();
}
```

Further variable names are lower case unless they are final then they are all upper case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Student[]Array1 = new Student[10];
```

fills `Array1` with 10 `null` entries.

And

```
Array1[i].setName(Scan.next());
```

will call `setName...` on `null` which results in `NullPointerException`.

One way to solve this issue would be:

```
1) Create new Student object inside for loop
2) call setName... on object created in step1
3) Set object to array index.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java arrays are objects so when you write:

`String[] asdf = new String[size];`

You don't create ten `String` objects stored in an array but only the array's object's with all it's elements (references) set to `null`.

What you should do is to create `Student` objects before setting it's properties:

```
 Array1[i] = new Student();    
 Array1[i].setName(Scan.next());
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to initialize the array's elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++) {
    Array1[i] = new Student();
}
```

This line: `Student[] Array1 = new Student[10];` creates an empty array, full of null elements. You have to instantiate each one in turn before using them, otherwise you'll get a nasty `NullPointerException` when you try to invoke a method (say, `setName()`) on an element in the array.

Same considerations apply to `ArrayF1`. And a matter of style - in Java variable and method names start with a lowercase character, only class, interface and enum names start with an uppercase character.